# Suppress java compiler warnings caused by parent class in packaged library

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

I'm extending a class in a packaged library and the class I'm extending causes an "unchecked" compiler warning. Please note it is not my class that is causing the warning and that is why this is different from other questions I found here in SO.

To comply with code standards in my company, my code must compile without warnings but I can't get rid of this one.

Initially, I wasn't even overriding the offending method. I have overridden it only to add the **@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")** annotation but that didn't solve the problem.

Within the library, an abstract class ClassA has this method:

```java
public abstract class ClassA {

    protected abstract <T> T methodA(
        String lockName, 
        TransactionCallback<T> txCallback);
}
```

Also within the library, another class ClassB extends ClassA causing the warning:

```java
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    @Override
    protected Object methodA(
            String lockName, 
            TransactionCallback txCallback) {
        return someOtherMethod(lockName, txCallback, null);
    }

}
```

This uses an unchecked operation so, when I try to compile my class:

```
public class ClassC extends ClassB {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  protected Object methodA(String lockName, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") TransactionCallback txCallback) {
    return super.methodA(lockName, txCallback);
  }

}
```

I get this warning:

```
    [javac]   protected Object methodA(String lockName, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") TransactionCallback txCallback)
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac]   return type requires unchecked conversion from Object to T
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>methodA(String,TransactionCallback<T>)
```

Is there a way to actually suppress the warning even though I can't recompile the offending class but only its descendant?

Comment: @Michael The message comes from compiling his own code.

Comment: I'm not recompiling the classes within the jar, only my class, which extends the class in the library. It seems odd to me as well, but I'm sure because don't have the source code of the offending class (or the complete library) in the classpath. In fact, if I remove my class, the warning does not appear at all.

Comment: @user207421, thanks for the tip, but I already tried that. If I do, the class doesn't compile because it is not really "overriding" the method. Technically, there could be situations in which you could call my method without being within the domain of the method in ClassB.

Comment: @Michael, I know I would, I'm not saying it compiles every class of every library. But not all classes from all libraries are being extended by code you are actually compiling. If I remove my class, I don't get the warning. If I remove that method from my class but keep extending the class in the library I do get the warning.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the answer, that solved the problem. I kindly disagree with your opinion about my statement being wrong. It is true that the existence of my class made the warning "present itself", but it is not my class doing the unsafe/unchecked operations. In any case, I really appreciate you taking your time to reproduce and solve the problem.

Comment: @MauricioPeccorini Sure, happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce. `@SuppressWarnings` at the class-level seems to work, for whatever reason.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ClassC extends ClassB
{
    protected Object methodA(String lockName, TransactionCallback txCallback) {
        return super.methodA(lockName, txCallback);
    }
}
```